# Ruby Each loop in Slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I want to be able to loop through an instance var through a javascript but I'm not quite sure how to make it work.

```
javascript:
  -@spots.each do |spot|
      map.addMarker({
        lat: "#{spot.latitude}",
        lng: "#{spot.longitude}",
        title: "spot",
      });
  });
```

What I tried:
Using <% @spots.each do |spot| %> and without the quotes for the #{}

Comment: Looks good to me.  What's the error or issue?

Comment: undefined local variable or method `spot'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that once you're in the `javascript:` slim block, you can't also do the ruby loop.

I was able to get this to mostly work

```
- @spots.each do |spot|
  javascript:
    map.addMarker({
      lat: #{spot.latitude},
      lng: #{spot.longitude},
      title: "spot"
    });
```

but that makes separate script tags for each `addMarker` call which seems pretty dumb.

You could also try putting the data on the page as JSON and then do the loop in Javascript.  Something like this:

```
javascript:
  var spots = #{raw @spots.to_json};
  var ii = 0;
  var nspots = spots.length;
  for(;ii<nspots;++ii) {
    theMap.addMarker(spots[ii]);
  }
```

You'd want to make sure that `theMap` is available by the time this stuff runs, but I think this might do the trick.  You should also check the JSON format of each @spot.  Depending on how you have JSON setup, each spot may look like

```
{'spot': { 'latitude': ###, 'longitude': ### } }
```

which means you'll have to dereference 
the object in the loop.

Comment: Looping the javascript worked perfectly! I felt like it wasn't very elegant the mix the languages that much. Thanks!

Comment: I was happy to see @xmpolaris gave basically the same answer - it validated my thinking.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

easy fix but not efficient if spots are too long.

```
-@spots.each do |spot|
  javascript:
    map.addMarker({
      lat: "#{spot.latitude}",
      lng: "#{spot.longitude}",
      title: "spot",
    });
```

2.
 loop in js instead of view context

```
javascript:
  var spots = #{@spots.to_json};
  $(spots).each(function(index, obj) {
    map.addMarker({
      lat: obj.latitude,
      lng: obj.longitude,
      title: "spot",
    });
  });
```